# Python2.7. Проблема со вставкой изображения на Label.

Tags: python, pil, изображения, tkinter, label

Форумчане, есть одна проблема. При попытке вставить изображение на Label вижу лишь квадрат с цветом самого окна, но с размерами изображения. Как можно исправить?

Вот ссылка на код: http://pastebin.com/kRz7TXxN
Вот ссылка на фото: http://s008.radikal.ru/i304/1503/8a/458d4eae16ea.png

Comment: Голосую за закрытие, т.к. ссылка на код больше недоступна.

Answer (score 1):

Изображение должно быть членом класса:

```
class image_class():
    #Объявление вызываемой функции из второй функции#
    def next_image(self, image_choice):
        self.image_open  = Image.open("../IMGS/img"+str(image_choice)+".gif")
        self.image_puton = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_open)
        self.image_label = Label(label_root,image=image_puton)
        self.image_label.pack()

...
```

Иначе оно будет отчищено сборщиком мусора Python и Вы получите описанный эффект.

Comment: Теперь получаю это: 
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1532, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Курсовая Работа\VirtualMuseum_Tkinter\MDLS\main.py", line 24, in <lambda>
    self.btnNI.bind("<Button-1>",lambda event, image_choice=i+1: self.next_image(image_choice))
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Курсовая Работа\VirtualMuseum_Tkinter\MDLS\main.py", line 10, in next_image
    self.image_puton = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image_open)
NameError: global name 'image_open' is not defined